# ERROR at line 7: ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

Tags: mysql

i tried to create a table and this is the code

```
CREATE TABLE Funtom_timesheet
(
timesheet_ID number(3) CONSTRAINT Fun_tmsheet_PK PRIMARY KEY,
Timesheet_emp number(3) NOT NULL REFERENCES funtom_employee,
Timesheet_hours number(2),
Timesheet_OT number(2) default 0,
Timesheet_approved number(3) CONSTRAINT chk_tmsht_apprvd CHECK(timesheet_approved <> timesheet_emp) REFERENCES funtom_employee(emp_id)
);
```

and the requirement said that timesheet_approved mustn't have as same value as

> timesheet_employee but it showed error  ERROR at line 7: ORA-02438:
>   Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

i'm still beginner in SQL , can someone help me to solved this problem?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hit this just today, and it's not the most obvious error message.

The solution I used was to place the check constraint in a separate `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` clause.

For your table, it would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Funtom_timesheet
(
timesheet_ID number(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Timesheet_emp number(3) NOT NULL REFERENCES funtom_employee,
Timesheet_hours number(2),
Timesheet_OT number(2) default 0,
Timesheet_approved number(3)
);

ALTER TABLE Funtom_timesheet
   ADD CONSTRAINT chk_tmsht_apprvd CHECK(timesheet_approved <> timesheet_emp) ;
```

I don't believe that your attempt at having an internal foreign key in the check constraint is necessary.